# ctrl + c keyboard event not working in as2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

I'm using Macromedia Flex 1.5 with AS 2.0, I want  to keep ctrl + c keyboard event for a datagrid, I'm trying following code, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
function myOnKeyDown() { 


                         if (Key.isDown (Key.CONTROL) && Key.isDown(67))
                                                    {                                                                               mx.controls.Alert.show("Copied Succesfully: ");
                                                    }
                                                      else
                           {
                             mx.controls.Alert.show("Press control + c to copy: ");
                           }
                   }

]]> 
</mx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="35%" id="cur1_DataGrid" sortableColumns="false" change="level1var.checkForChanges()" keyDown="myOnKeyDown()">
```

Comment: Can you fill in a few more details? Does your myOnKeyDown run for other keys (making your alert message show up)? If you log/alert `Key.isDown(Key.Control)` and `Key.isDown(67)` when you're pressing those keys, do they return true?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tracking the state of the CTRL key and I'm okay with the results except when it comes to key combinations.

Press the CTRL key and you'll see it traces "CTRL on". Release it and you'll see it traces "CTRL off". No problem there. Now press CTRL and then press the C key (as in copy), now release C, then release the CTRL key and you see nothing traces.

i.e, if(Key.isDown(67))  is returning true................... (or)
     if(Key.isDown(Key.CONTROL)) is returning true.........

but (Key.isDown(Key.CONTROL) and Key.isDown(67)) is not returning......